# Digital Signature Modal from InfoPath Form in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, infopath, forms-authentication, digital-signature

I currently have 4 views created in InfoPath, using Form Load for a Approval Process in SharePoint 2010. I would like to use Digital Signatures for each approvers signature but the Modal view that appears when signing the document digitally has a partial view of the current form view being authenticated. I am also worried about end-users who do not have permissions to install the required Internet Explorer add-on so they may use the digital signature feature in InfoPath and SharePoint 2010.

- Is is possible to edit/customize the Modal?
- Can I force the system to use ActivClient or PIV rather than the default Modal?
- How can I control what part of the form is displayed in the Modal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveClient has an API.  You can install it from the installation media.  With that you could create a custom form that utilizes it.  I'm not aware of any office API that will allow you to modify the default behavior for handling digital certificates.

I would stay away from it if possible, especially if your shop is not managing the client configurations.  We've had way more issues troubleshooting client policies and configurations than it was worth.  If your deployment is configured for PKI authentications already, and you restrict username/password logon, than the access stamps provided by SharePoint should be adequate. You can even take that information and feed it to InfoPath as a suedo signature.

Other CONS:

If you use multiple signature, it can take minutes to open a form as the signatures are validated. We have a form with 4 Signatures and it    takes over 5 minutes to validate, so test heavily before relying on    them.  this is not an InfoPath specific item, as PDF and Word forms    will do the same thing.

When a cert if revoked or expired it shows up in the form as invalid.  So if you are looking for something to store for long term user, this    may not be it, as new users get CAC/PIV's there old signatures will    no longer be valid when the form is viewed.

If you want to validate an entire form, you can only do it via the thick client. Browser forms only do form sections.

Comment: Thank you... I started moving in the direction of using the access stamps yesterday after posting this question.  The Cons that you listed on revoked or expired certs in the future is the exact reason for the shift in plans. This is for the GOV so keeping the forms for a long period of time and changes in status of the certificate is a nightmare waiting to happen.